# Civisualize can't find JS and CSS resources

Tags: civisualize

I've got Civisualize running very nicely on an installation of CiviCRM 4.5 and Drupal 7 with some custom templates and queries. I then moved a copy of the whole site across to a different server under a different URL. After a bit of fiddling around, everything is now working under the new server/URL, except for Civisualize. I can access the dataviz template pages but no graphs/data are displayed.

The problem stems from the Civisualize extension looking for the d3 javascript and css resources in a place that they're not but I've no idea how to force/trick/coerce Civisualize to look for them elsewhere. Directories and Custom Ext path have been set up correctly and disabling/uninstalling/re-installing the extension hasn't helped.

Any suggestions as to what to try next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the url where civi looks for extension so it looks at the new url

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1